# How to start dragging marker programmatically (leaflet)

Tags: leaflet, google-maps-markers, draggable, mousedown

I want to start marker dragging after 2 seconds on the mousedown.
I know how to enable/disable the dragging, but not find how to start dragging by code.

I tried :

```
marker.on('mousedown', function(e){
    setTimeout(() => {
        marker.dragging.enable();
        marker.dragging._draggable._onDown(e);
    }, 2000);
});
```

The draggable option is enable, but the marker does not move.

Of course, I can move it on the 2nd mousedown.

Answer (score 1):

this is solve my problem :

```
marker.on('mousedown', function(e){
    setTimeout(() => {

        map.dragging._draggable.finishDrag();

        marker.dragging.enable();
        marker.dragging._draggable._onDown(e.originalEvent);
    }, 2000);
});
```